# How to check and get value of lambda which has a value of string and expression

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

Declaration:

```
Func<dynamic,oject> format;
```

Provide value:

```
format: @<text> <input type="checkbox" checked="" /> </text>)
format: (itm) => { return itm.Name + " Somtheing <a>Click Here</a> "
```

Im looking for the output which is this,

Output 1. (here no problem)

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="" />
```

Output 2.

```
if (Itm.Name is "Rose") 
then Output should be "Rose Somtheing <a>Click Here</a>") 

but i got the error here which is 
'System.Array' does not contain a definition for 'Name' ).
```

Here is the code

```
var obj = format.GetInvocationList();
var result = c.Format(obj);
```

Any sugesstion here?

Comment: Hi thanks, for the help.. i already found the answer to my question.
What i did is pass the dynamic model to c.Format(model);
The result would do anything its either string or expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closed: Already found the solution to the problem.
What i did is get the current row in model or object that holds the current data

instead of using

```
var obj = format.GetInvocationList();
```

i changed it too

```
object row = GetCurrentRows();
var result = c.Format(row);
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the spelling of item/itm

Try:

```
format: (item) => { return item.Name + " Somtheing <a>Click Here</a> "
```

Instead of:

```
format: (item) => { return itm.Name + " Somtheing <a>Click Here</a> "
```